# Finding groups of elements and nesting them in a new element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just getting started with Javascript and am struggling to find a way to:

1. Find one or more consecutive elements of the same type, e.g. `<p>…</p>` or `<p>…</p><p>…</p>`
2. Surround each group with a new element, e.g. `<dd><p>…</p></dd>` or `<dd><p>…</p><p>…</p></dd>`

I'd also like to limit the script so that it applies only to a particular part of the page, e.g. `<div id="relevantbit"></div>`, but perhaps that counts as a separate question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is a native javascript function that will wrap consecutive tags at the same level in whatever type of tag you want it wrapped in.  It even works recursively so it will find them to any level.  As written, when detecting consecutive tags, it ignores non-elements such as text nodes or comment nodes, but it could easily be modified if that was not the desired behavior (that detail wasn't specified).

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Bp97p/.

And here's the code:

```
function wrapConsecutive(parent, desiredTagName, wrapTag) {

    desiredTagName = desiredTagName.toUpperCase();
    if (typeof parent === "string") {
        parent = document.getElementById(parent);
    }

    function wrapNodes(nodeBegin, nodeEnd) {
        // create and insert the wrap node
        var wrapNode = document.createElement(wrapTag);
        nodeBegin.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapNode, nodeBegin);
        // now move the matched nodes into the wrap node
        var node = nodeBegin, next;
        while (node) {
            next = node.nextSibling;
            wrapNode.appendChild(node);
            if (node === nodeEnd) {
                break;
            }
            node = next;
        }
    }

    function wrapChildren(parent) {
        var next = parent.firstChild;
        var firstInSeries = null;
        var lastInSeries;
        while (next) {
            // only look at element nodes
            if (next.nodeType === 1) {
                wrapChildren(next);
                if (next.tagName === desiredTagName) {
                    // found a matching tagName
                    // if we don't have a series yet, start one
                    // if we do have a series, just keep going
                    if (!firstInSeries) {
                        firstInSeries = next;
                    }
                    lastInSeries = next;
                } else {
                    // did not find a matching tagName
                    // if we have a series, then end the series and process it
                    // if we didn't have a series yet, then keep looking for one
                    if (firstInSeries) {
                        // wrap from firstInSeries to next.previousSibling
                        wrapNodes(firstInSeries, lastInSeries);
                        firstInSeries = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            next = next.nextSibling;
        }
        if (firstInSeries) {
            wrapNodes(firstInSeries, lastInSeries);
        }
    }
    wrapChildren(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Huge helpful and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would translate these gymnastics to native javascript, but using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could make your own method: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZh9T/3/)

```
jQuery.fn.wrapConsecutive = function(desiredTagName, wrapTag) {
    $(this).find(desiredTagName).each(function(i, element){
        var $target = $(element);
        $consecutive = $target;
        if(!$target.prev().length || $target.prev().get(0).tagName!==desiredTagName){
            while($target.next().length && $target.next().get(0).tagName===desiredTagName){
                $target = $target.next();
                $consecutive = $consecutive.add($target);
            }
            $consecutive.wrapAll('<' + wrapTag + ' />');
        }
    });
}
$('#relevantbit').wrapConsecutive('P','dd');​
```

1. Grab each of the element type that we are hoping to wrap in groups
2. Check each one to see if it is the start of a new group
3. Check if there is a next sibling, and if so whether it also matches our type
4. Wrap the finished group

PS: Thanks for the comments, this answer has been heavily revised.

Comment: I think it might be a hair more complicated than that. If you're looking at `p+p`, I think @Duncano wants to end up with <div><p>..</p><p>..</p></div>. Let's see what he says.

Comment: You may want to explain that you're introducing the OP to jQuery.

Comment: @paislee Sorry, sometimes I forget that I follow js questions as well as jQuery questions.

Comment: This doesn't find consecutive `<p>` tags and wrap the consecutive `<p>` tags with one `<dd>`.  I don't think this is what the OP asked for.  And, it's jQuery which also isn't what was asked for.

Comment: You guys are totally right. I misread the question, I will post a corrected version.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone and for revising it @Sinetheta. I'll take a look at the native JS version first as figure I should learn to walk before trying to run!

Comment: This doesn't quite work right.  If you fix your HTML to be legal HTML like I did here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pZh9T/ by putting the proper close tags on the `<li>` and `<ul>` tags, then you will find that the line `if($(this).index() === 0){` doesn't do what is needed to make the algorithm work.

Comment: How about that change? Now it makes a guarded inspect to check if either of the two cases "there is no previous sibling" or "the previous sibling is another tag (so we've started a new group)"